# How do I make a video full screen using actionscript in flex desktop application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am playing a flv video using the videoplayer class of flex. (all the properties of it are being set at runtime)

I want to make the video fullscreen without clicking on the fullscreen button i.e. through programming.

Is it possible. If yes then how can I do this.?

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch click event from the fullScreenButton of VideoPlayer.

```
yourplayer.fullScreenButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [displayState](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState) property of the stage.  You can access the stage as a variable on the Application class.  So, conceptually, do this:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN
```

run this code in an applicationComplete event handler on the main application tag to put your app into full screen mode after it is finished loading.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I am trying to make my videoplayer toggle to run in fullscreen by default. I am using flex 4 videoplayer class

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma Why does my answer not tell you how to do it?  did you try it and have a problem?  If so, what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the VideoDisplay from it's parent and then add it to the stage at full width & height. Reverse the process when exiting full screen.

```
protected function fullScreenBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    videoContainer.removeChild(videoDisplay)        
    this.stage.addChild(videoDisplay);
    this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    videoDisplay.width = stage.width;
    videoDisplay.height = stage.height;
    this.stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenHandler);
}

protected function fullScreenHandler(event:FullScreenEvent):void
{
    if(!event.fullScreen)
    {
        this.stage.removeChild(videoDisplay);
        this.videoContainer.addChild(videoDisplay);
        videoDisplay.percentHeight = videoDisplay.percentWidth = 100;
        this.stage.removeEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenHandler);
    }
}
```