# How do I just fullscreen the Videodisplay and not the whole application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, red5, videochat

I'm working on a video chat in Flex with Red5. I'm using the following code:

```
    stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(vidDisp.x,vidDisp.y, vidDisp.width, vidDisp.height);
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN
```

This code gives me a weird half cut fullscreen. Does anyone know any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: I have some sample code for this in my answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107692/how-do-i-make-a-video-full-screen-using-actionscript-in-flex-desktop-application/10620687#10620687

Comment: @RobertCesaric
What is videoContainer in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Siddharth here's the videoContainer from that implementation:

```
<!--Video Player-->
<mx:Box id="videoContainer" width="100%" height="{Math.floor(this.width * 0.6)}">
    <mx:VideoDisplay id="player" width="100%" height="100%" autoPlay="false" autoRewind="false" bufferTime="4" playheadUpdateInterval="1000"  />
</mx:Box>
```